# How to integrate Standalone GeowebCache with Geoserver on different machine

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, standalone

We are trying to configure Standalone GeoWebCache on a server. The WMS service is hosted on different server in Geoserver.

How should we fetch WMS layers in GWC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the config file (see http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/layers/howto.html#how-to-configure-layers for details of where that is), you then need to find the `wmsLayers` section of the document and within that there should be a `gwc:WmsUrl` element that you can change.

Comment: Where to find wmsLayers section?

Comment: ok i found it in geowebcache.xml. But this file is in Geoserver on different server. I am trying to connect standalone GWC from another server to Geoserver.